# Does this corollary proved by Segal contradicts the first postulate of QM? Any examples?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, ising-model

I was studying the algebraic formalism of QM, and I have read this Corollary proved by Segal in 1947:

"There exist pure states $\omega$ of $\mathfrak{C}$ (the system of all bounded self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space) which are not of the form $\omega (U)=(Ux,x)$ for some element x of the Hilbert space."

Here, $U\in\mathfrak{C}$ is an observable, (,) is the scalar product and $\omega$ is a linear functional defined from $\mathfrak{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (the usual definition of state in algebraic QM).

This made me think about the first postulate of QM in Dirac-von Neumann formalism, and I thought that the corollary contradicts it. I was looking for examples where you can't normalise a pure state given his wave function, or that you can't express it as a unitary transformation of other pure state. Looking for this, the ground state of the quantum Ising model came to mind, but I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding this Segal's corollary. Any ideas?

Comment: The first postulate literally just says "we don't care about operators that are not self-adjoint". It's a value judgement.

Comment: @ConnorBehan right, I understand that, but my question is that if there are "practical" examples where you can't express a pure state (or a transformation of it) like a vector in a Hilbert space, as I can interpret just following the corollary. Thanks

Comment: You mean an experiment where modelling it in the old way leads to the wrong answer but including the more general states found by Segal leads to the right one?

Comment: @ConnorBehan not necessarily that (it would be amazing but I think that it is so hard to find). For example, when you consider a system with infinite degrees of freedom, you can’t use Hilbert spaces anymore. But I don’t know examples where this can be useful, maybe in Statistical Mechanics or QFT (I only know the theoretical fact). More specifically, I’m looking for an example where it is not possible to express a physical state as a unitary vector of a Hilbert space, and Operator Algebras (or something related to that) are necessary.